# Notes error: Index is not to be generated on server. (View Name)

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a database that need to have dynamic views. The view selection will changed based on the user roles. I'm using "Shared, private on first use" views to do this so that when the user opens it for the first time a new separate view is created for her.

It works if I'm not first time opening the database as private views already created on my machine. The problem comes for the first time user. If they are first time accessing the database, they will recieve this error message:

Notes Error: Index is not to be generated on server ("*view name*")

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Check the database ACL.  There is a checkbox labeled "Create personal folders/views".  Is this box checked for your users?

Comment: Richard, it's already checked. Now it seems like the index is not generated on the first time used.

Comment: Try removing that check-box for the end-users.  I think that will cause the private view to be built and stored on the user's local machine instead of on the server.  (However, I should also point out that you may want to reconsider this design.  'Shared/private on first use' views are difficult to maintain over time.  You might be better off using an embedded view with the 'Show single category' feature instead.)

Comment: Also, there are two IBM technotes that cover the error message that you are seeing.  1)  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21094072  2) http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21206947